# OCMock: Mock objects that implement several protocols?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

```
id protocolMock = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(SomeProtocol));
```

Will create a mock object that can be used as if it were an instance of an object that implements SomeProtocol.

Does OCMock provide a way to create a mock object that implements several protocols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your test file, you can create a new protocol that implements the multiple ones you need:

```
@protocol MyTestProtocol <MyProtocolA, MyProtocolB>
@end
```

and then mock it:

```
id protocolMock = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(MyTestProtocol));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported in OCMock. If you think this is a feature that really should be added, please log an issue on Github (https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues).